# assign values to points according to nearest points values

Tags: python, heatmap

I have a list of points with `X` and `Y` coordinates (around 8,000). For some of them (aroud 160 or 2%), I have an additional information `E`, here for *elevation*. I would like to know if there is any method to calculate and assign a `E` value for each points, depending on its location, and the `E` value of the closest points.

May be this representation would help to understand:

[points representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqBf7.png)

Only red points have a value `E`, and I would like to assign a value to all blue points according to their position in relation to the red points and their value.

I have the image of an heat map that could give a value for each point, but I don't know if it is possible. Any idea? I would like to do it in python.

Comment: I guess you could calculate the distance of each blue point one by one to every red point to get the nearest red point, and depending on the E of the red point/distance, assign an E to the point. Does this sound correct?

Comment: yes, it sounds correct, but when a blue point is between two red points, it should give a value depending one the distance and the value of each of them, and then it gets more complicated if the blue point is surrounded by more points. Wouldn't it be possible to create a sort of heat map just with the red points and assign a value to the blue ones based on the results of this map?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! A heatmap sure would work, maybe defining square regions where the E is set, and the blue points get the E of the region they are in. To define the E of the regions, maybe using the 3 or 4 nearest red points to the region? Or maybe even all the red points?

Comment: Yes, that's it! sorry for bad explanations. May be all the red points will be better. So first will be to make an heat map with the red points, and after locate blue points on the heat map, and then assign the value of this region to points. Is that it?

Comment: Yes exactly ! If you want some help, could you provide the dataset? I thihnk it would be easier

Comment: how should I do to share the dataset?